# Is datacenter a lan?

Tags: lan, terminology

A datacenter can contains thousands of machines. At very high level is it just a LAN and private network with thousands of machines on them.

1. Is datacenter a LAN ? or is it WAN ?
2. Is datacenter a private network ? Do all machines on datacenter fall in private subnets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term LAN is rather amorphous.  It can mean a single broadcast domain, a network on a single cable plant, a network in a building or small group of close buildings, etc.

As far as the broadcast domain definition, a data center could have multiple LANs, separated by routers.  It really depends on the definition of LAN which you are using.

A data center could use private addressing, it could be using public addressing, or it could be using a mixture of public and private addressing.

Also, you will find many definitions for data center, too.

You won't find single answers to your questions without more detail and context.

Comment: eg you may have a datacentre at a vendor's datacentre, where they host others' datacentres. That could be called a collo (Co-Location facility). Your datacentre there may be on a LAN, but perhaps you have to go across a site-to-site tunnel over your internet connection to get to it. That could then be called a WAN. But to your applications it's just a LAN. These terms are a lot like the Pirate Code: They're more like guidelines.